# Converting the dataframe from long to wide using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

my sample `df` looks like this

```
student_id,      year,       grade,    school   
1001           20002001        1         abc  
1001           20012002        2         abc 
1001           20022003        3         abc 
1001           20032004        4         abc  

1002           19992000        2         abc    
1002           20002001        3         abc         
1002           20012002        4         abc         

1003           20022003        4         abc          

1004           20022003        3         abc         
1004           20032004        4         abc
```

this `df` is currently in `long` format. what I want to do is transform the data into a `wide` format, which should look like this:

```
student_id,    grade_19992000,    grade_20002001,    grade_20012002,    grade_20022003,    grade_20032004,    school_19992000,   school_19992000,   school_20012002,    school_20022003,    school_20032004     
1001                NaN                  1                  2                  3              4                       NaN                 abc                 abc                 abc                 abc
1002                2                    3                  4                 NaN            NaN                     abc                 abc                 abc                 NaN                 NaN 
1003                NaN                 NaN                NaN                 4             NaN                     NaN                 NaN                 NaN                  abc                    NaN 
1004                NaN                 NaN                NaN                 3             4                     NaN                 NaN                 abc                  abc                    NaN
```

*this is not duplicate nor related to other questions. I tried all available options.*

**What did I do?**

- I tried to use `df.pivot(index='', columns'', values='')` but it did not format the data as I wanted
- for example: for `student_id` with the same `year`, it created a new columns with *same column name* for the other `student_id` and so on...

Could someone please provide some insight on how I can achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `pivot`; only you need 2 columns as values:

```
out = df.pivot('student_id', 'year', ['grade', 'school'])
out.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in out.columns]
```

Output:

```
           grade_19992000 grade_20002001 grade_20012002 grade_20022003  \
student_id                                                               
1001                  NaN              1              2              3   
1002                    2              3              4            NaN   
1003                  NaN            NaN            NaN              4   
1004                  NaN            NaN            NaN              3   

           grade_20032004 school_19992000 school_20002001 school_20012002  \
student_id                                                                  
1001                    4             NaN             abc             abc   
1002                  NaN             abc             abc             abc   
1003                  NaN             NaN             NaN             NaN   
1004                    4             NaN             NaN             NaN   

           school_20022003 school_20032004  
student_id                                  
1001                   abc             abc  
1002                   NaN             NaN  
1003                   abc             NaN  
1004                   abc             abc
```

Comment: thanks for composing the answer. I am getting this error `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: after following `https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/reshaping.html` I also tried `pivot_table()` but it still does not work

Comment: @floss So exactly like the error says, there are duplicate values either in index or in columns. My guess is there is at least one student_id that has the same grade in different years. Without knowing what you actually have can't say more. The code works on your current sample. Please edit your question with a sample that reproduces your problem.

Comment: is there a way to check the duplicates? I tried `groupby(by=['student_id', 'grade']).count()` not sure if this is the correct way...

Comment: @floss that's great. If you don't mind, what was causing the duplicity problem?

Comment: there were duplicates in the data, I figured it out using `set()`. I am not exactly sure what is causing the duplication, I may have not prepared the data well. checking on that... may be while merging the data, i am not using proper `join`

Comment: @floss if there are duplicate rows, you can drop them using `drop_duplicates`. Assuming no one repeats a grade, something like: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['student_id','grade'])` could help.